How to view real-time log of all varnish cache evictions (lru nuked, purged, banned, expired, etc)
How can I view the objects that are removed from the varnish cache in real-time?
I know that I can monitor for PURGE events using varnishlog, and I know that I can monitor varnishstat to see the counts of objects evicted, banned, and lru nuked.
But how can I actually view what is removed from varnish's cache live (as it happens)?

Is this just idle curiosity,  or is there a problem you're trying to solve? Since, in general, caches are associated with speeding things up, it's unlikely that cache ejection is a heavily logged event.

I'm afraid varnishlog is the only way.
For regular purges you could run the following command:
varnishlog -g request -q "VCL_call eq 'PURGE'"

For other invalidations that use the PURGE request method, you could just filter on the PURGE method like this:
varnishlog -g request -q "ReqMethod eq 'PURGE'"

If you're using the ban() function VCL, you can always run the varnishadm ban.list command to see what's on the ban list.
You can also run the following command to capture the varnishlog transaction ids for banned lookups:
varnishlog -g raw -q ExpBan

The output will present you with a VXID of a banned lookup. You can then run the following command to find that transaction in the logs:
varnishlog -g request -q "vxid == 123"

Just replace 123 with the actual VXID you want to filter on.
Ultimately, the logs are the only way to monitor cache invalidations in real time.

Do "LRU nuke" events show up as a PURGE in varnishlog too? Are there any other types of events where an object is removed from the varnish cache that won't be shown as a PURGE in varnishlog (eg expired, banned, etc)?

@MichaelAltfield have a look at https://varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/reference/vsl.html and search for ExpKill, you'll find all the eviction events it logs.
